# Multidimensioan PHP Array Group By Value of First Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem with logical grouping of multidimensional Array as shown below.

```
 Array
 (
     [id] => Array
         (
             [0] => B
             [1] => C
             [2] => D
             [3] => A
         )

     [value] => Array
         (
             [0] => 1500000
             [1] => 200000
             [2] => 250000
             [3] => 100000
         )

     [desc] => Array
         (
             [0] => DESC B
             [1] => DESC C
             [2] => DESC D
             [3] => DESC A
         )

     [type] => Array
         (
             [0] => 1
             [1] => 1
             [2] => 1
             [3] => 1
         )

     [userid] => 1312
 )
```

I want to insert to database each row grouped by name each row, e.g:

```
 id | name | value  | desc   | type | userid
---------------------------------------------
 1  | A    | 100000 | DESC A | 1    | 1312
 2  | B    | 150000 | DESC B | 1    | 1312
 3  | C    | 200000 | DESC B | 1    | 1312
```

Am I using double foreach to group by name or anything else to solve this problems?

Comment: Please post the php code that is failing, ... are you correctly handling that the `userid` is not itself a 2 dimensional array like the others are?

Comment: Please post the db abstraction layer mysqli? pdo? or any ORM?

Comment: @Viney, I'm using mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to recycle the keys of one array for the output of the others and make new groups

```
$data = array();
foreach($id as $i => $dummy){
 $data[] = array($id[$i], $value[$i], $desc[$i], $type[$i], $userid);
}
```